# How discovery if data center provider is keeping network transfer logs or listening for traffic of the VPN provider?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

How do I know if the data center provider is keeping network transfer logs or listening for traffic on both inbound and outbound connections of my VPN service hosted in their infrastructure? I mean does exists some practical way to check this or do I need to rely on the trust?

Comment: Yes, if you use quantum communication systems (entangled photons that change spin when observed), no otherwise.

Comment: In many jurisdictions communications service providers face a mandatory legal requirement to provide intercept facilities to local law enforcement. A fairly typical method is that the ISP send a copy of every signal that crosses the wire to a suspects subscriber number to a police intercept. Unlike in the analog era (when you might have heard an echo or the click of a tape reel) you can't detect that. period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell if anyone on the network path between two points is inspecting the traffic that is passing through, if all you control are the two end points.

Comment: my concern is only about the data center "sniffing" packets without my knowledge, others nodes in the network path, I do not really care, since I would to provide a real almost no log service from my infrastructure (include rented data center), otherwise I should have my own server to host the openVPN and forget the hassles of the data center. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't think so the statement is fully right because VPN providers use a seprate network hosted in very different locations, the only way it may be possible if VPN provider themselves start trading the information.

Comment: for example, my vpn has the follow ip 10.10.10.10, someone to reach that ip, need to pass through at least 4 computers inside the network that I host the service. that is my concern, if they tcpdump the packets .. how can one vpn company be so sure to offer a service saying "zero logs" or whatever they say.. if scenarios like this is all around? did you get it? in doubt traceroute always!